# Guardar los valores devueltos por api java

Tags: java

Estoy intentando guardar los valores que me arroja un api hecha en java. Encontré un ejemplo(mostrado a continuación), pero al momento de ejecutarlo solo me brinda como respuesta un estado 200, y no los datos. ¿alguna sugerencia?

```
 BuscarP bsp = new BuscarP();//mi objeto
            bsp.setUser(txtUserLog.getValue());
            bsp.setPwd(pswPwdLog.getValue());
            ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
            clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
            Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
            WebResource webResource = client.resource("MI URL" + txtUserLog.getValue());
            ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
            bsp = response.getEntity(BuscarP.class);
```

Comment: Tu entidad... ¿En qué parte de tu resuesta HTTP viene?

Comment: Puedes subir la respuesta en el debug de lo que genra la linea 8 por que puedes que el error sea el parse de JSON a objeto